# Firewall detected while mounting volume in docker

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I am trying to mount volume using share drive option on Docker-Desktop but each time, when I am click on Drive to share it, I am getting below error:

My docker version is : 2.1.0.5
My System : Windows 10

[image]

[image]

I am on my office system and connected to internet using VPN. I have disconnected my VPN and tried to connect to internet directly, still I am getting this error. I don't have full access to modify settings on my laptop. I really need mount option to share some file between local machine and container and I am not able to do it. Could you please help me to resolve this issue or any workaround that I could try to mount my local files to container without sharing Drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to upgrade to a 2.2.x.x release of docker desktop or newer. In [that release](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#docker-desktop-community-2200) they updated the file sharing to remove the samba based mounts.

> - Users don’t have to expose the Samba port, and therefore do not experience issues related to IT firewall or drive-sharing policy.

There were a few issues in the first few releases, so be sure to use the latest patch.